# Can't install php5-curl in ubuntu server 14.04

Tags: ubuntu

Whenever I run `sudo apt-get install php5-curl` I get

```
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

And after inputing **Y** I get the following:

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed. perl: warning: Please check that
your locale settings are supported and installed on your system.erl:
warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C"). locale: Cannot set
LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory Setting up
php5-cli (5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.5) ... locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to
default locale: No such file or directory ucfr: Attempt from package
php5-cli  to take /etc/php5/cli/php.ini away from package php5-fpm
ucfr: Aborting. dpkg: error processing package php5-cli (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit
 status 4 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of
 php5-readline:  php5-readline depends on php5-cli (=
 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.5); however:   Package php5-cli is not configured yet.

 dpkg: error processing package php5-readline (--configure): 
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems
 prevent configuration of php-pear:  php-pear depends on php5-cli;
 however:   Package php5-cli is not configured yet.

 dpkg: error processing package php-pear (--configure):  dependency
 problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems prevent
 configuration of php5-geoip:  php5-geoip depends on php-pear (>=
 1.4.0~b1); however:   Package php-pear is not configured yet.

 dpkg: error processing package php5-geoip (--configure):  dependency
 problems - leaving unconfigured No apport report written because the
 error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                    No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                       No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
              E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've been trying **everything** to solve this, from purging to removing php5, cleaning, updating and upgrading packages but still I achieved nothing... can someone **please** help me on this one? I'm getting desperate alright...

Answer (score 0):

Try using "apt-get install -f" it should install dependencies needed.

Comment: Also outputs the above, starting with `setting up php5-cli` and including `dpkg: error processing package php5-cli`...